# Car doesn't shift smoothly

Tags: engine, shifting, gears

I have a 2003 GMC Sierra with 60,000 miles on it. I have automatic transmission and just a few weeks ago, my car started having problems shifting gears. The best way to describe how the car feels would be like driving a stick shift. There is a delay between gear shifts and it is very jumpy.

In addition, since I have started having this issue, my engine has cut out three times while I'm at a stoplight, although the rest of my car remains on (lights, radio etc). I just put it in park, restart the car, and then it works just fine.

Sometimes when I'm stopped at a stop sign or stoplight with my brakes on, I can hear my engine rev slightly higher than usual and I can feel my truck move slightly forward, like I had just gently pressed the gas pedal, although I'm obviously not. I am not car savvy and could use some help with this problem. Any insight?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the car, but it could have a vacuum pipe going to the transmission.  I have seen identical symptoms when this pipe was disconnected or split.
If this is the case, the transmission will not be getting the vacuum it needs, hence the jerky change and the engine will be getting unmetered air which will cause the high revs etc.